# The webpage at file:///android_asset/file.html could not be loaded because: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: java, android

I don't why I'm getting an error:-

> The webpage at file:///android_asset/file.html could not be loaded because:
> net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

```
WebSettings mysettings = myweb.getSettings();
        
        mysettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mysettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        
        myweb.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/file.html");
        
        myweb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

Here Is my file

> /RandomPasswordGenerator/app/src/main/assets/www/file.html

Comment: Shouldn't that be "file://" rather than "file:///"?

Comment: @NomadMaker it has to be file:///

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that you have not created another folder called **android_asset**. Since you've not shown your assets directory, let the **www** folder be inside the **assets** folder **(app > src > main >assets)**.
The matter is, what you must give as 'android_asset' is actually shown as 'assets' in the directory listing. With this, you can find yourself a solution by rightly targeting your files.